# my validation Form Dosent work and i dont know why?

Tags: javascript, html

My validation Form doesn't work at all and I don't know why, it seems to be okay

```js
     function Validator(){
            if(document.shahab_Form.TheCheckBox.checked)
            {
                alert("it's already Checked my Friend!");
            }
            else
            {
             alert("no it's not checked my friend");
            }
        }
```

```html
    <form name="Shahab_Forms">
            <input type="checkbox" name="TheCheckBox"/>
            <input type="button" value="Press Me" onclick="Validator();"/> 
    </form>
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive

Comment: `Shahab_Forms` with s !

Comment: Tnx Very Very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is caseSensitive. `Shahab_Forms` is not same as `shahab_forms`.
There are 2 mistakes in your code:

1)caseSenstivity i.e `shahab_Forms` vs `Shahab_Forms`

2)You made a typo :`shahab_Form`. You missed 's' at the end.

Below is your working code

```js
 function Validator(){
            if(document.Shahab_Forms.TheCheckBox.checked)
            {
                alert("it's already Checked my Friend!");
            }
            else
            {
             alert("no it's not checked my friend");
            }
        }
```

```html
   
 <form name="Shahab_Forms">
            <input type="checkbox" name="TheCheckBox"/>
            <input type="button" value="Press Me" onclick="Validator();"/> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
     function Validator(){
            if(document.shahab_Form.TheCheckBox.checked)
            {
                alert("it's already Checked my Friend!");
            }
            else
            {
             alert("no it's not checked my friend");
            }
        }
```

```html
    <form name="Shahab_Forms">
            <input type="checkbox" name="TheCheckBox"/>
            <input type="button" value="Press Me" onclick="Validator();"/> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Your code does not work. I get an error when I run it.